# Which company name to write when signing in as a subcontractor?

Tags: contractors, independent-contractor, subcontracting

I'll soon have my first day with my new client and I'm a subcontractor. I don't expect to have an employee badge the first day so I guess I should sign in as any visitor at the front desk (unless other instructions will be given by the manager).

Should I write the name of my own Single-Person Limited Liability Company (subcontractor) or the name of the contractor that has a direct relationship with the client?

The client probably has no idea that my LLC even exists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should ask your contact at the main contractor company. Most probable is that you use their name since they have the contract with the customer, but this is not a given. Just ask, communication is key.

Answer (score 5):

I've always signed in with the name of the contractor company that has a direct relationship with the client.

Answer (score 4):

> The client probably has no idea that my LLC even exists.

Do not make things confusing.

Unless you're a plumber/electrician/tradesman with some kind of required license under your company name, use the name of the contractor that has a direct relationship with the client.

A badge or an attendance sheet is not a tax form. Besides, if it's like in the US, the client company will most likely always invoice the intermediary contractor, not your company.